# Scale object from a direction in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, scale

When I currently scale objects they always scale from the top left. Is there a way to set a different scaling starting point, like for example in Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the `scale` option on the top toolbar, you can select a scale reference point. Here's an example where the center is selected.

[image]

You can also scale with shortcuts like this :

(Quoting the official [Sketch documentation](https://www.sketch.com/docs/layer-basics/resizing-layers/))

> So, to scale a layer so that it’s 50 pixels wide, from the right, you’d set its width to 50r.

[image]

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds :)

Comment: Oh! Don't hesitate to edit my post if you had more useful information :)

Comment: Nice, but I usually scale from the side bar, is it possible to get that option there too?

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof I've added a link to the sketch documentation with another way to scale from the sidebar. Is this more useful?

Comment: It's better thanks. I wish Sketch added that little symbol thingy to the side bar too